# 401 Unauthorized -- Invalid grant when requesting refresh token in Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, doorkeeper

I'm having a trouble in requesting a refresh token, it keep returning an Unauthorized 401 error. I don't know if I'm lacking a parameters that I passed when I did a request.

I added the doorkeeper configuration for refresh token.

`use_refresh_token`

Here's the request details:

`{{root_url}}/oauth/token`

```
{"refresh_token"=>"034a74c085219fb8297fd8ef9b59f080918f"
 "format"=>:json,
 "controller"=>"/oauth/tokens",
 "action"=>"create",
 "grant_type"=>"refresh_token",
 "client_id"=>"<client_id>",
 "client_secret"=> "<client_secret>"}
```

Error descriptions:

```
{:error=>:invalid_grant,
 :error_description=>
  "The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."}
```

Btw, all of my api request authentication is not failing just this refresh token. I wonder what I'm missing in the request parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Do not pass the client_id and client_secret.

The required parameters for the refresh token are:

- grant_type
- refresh_token

Optional parameter:

- scope.

See the [Refresh Token section of rfc6749: The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6)

Comment: Yup. I read that documentation after I post here. But I wonder why treat the as invalid grant type even I have the correct grant type and valid refresh token? why not just ignore the extra params that send in request? any idea. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I think because these are authorization requests which should be treated strictly.

Comment: True, It might be when you pass a client and secret they thought it's a different grant type and disregard the exact grant type and token. I think your it makes sense. Thanks!