# Authentication using Resource Owner Password Credentials in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am considerably new to OAuth authentication scheme. What pose a problem for me at the moment is getting access_token from server in Rails app.

So far I read few articles covering methods related to Resource Owner Password Credentials in OAuth 2.0, but still it got me nowhere.
To name a few [Official documentation regarding ROPC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-15#section-4.3) / [Introduction to OAuth2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) / [Description of OAuth2 gem from Intridea](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2)

Server that I want to connect with allows password grant. It's deployed by 3rd party, so I assume everything is ok with it. On manual page they defined example of authorization as follows:

```
curl -X POST -d
'grant_type=password&username=USER_EMAIL&password=YOUR_PASSWORD&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET'
'https://auth.example.com/oauth2/token'
```

I posses all data which is mentioned above. BTW, client_id and client_secret are generic values enclosed in documentation. Server uses Doorkeeper gem to implement OAuth2.

To retrieve access_token from server, I simply put advised by Doorkeeper's wiki code into one of my controllers. [Testing ROPC for Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow#testing)

My code in Rails API app utilizing [OAuth2 gem](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) from Intridea:

```
 def test
    client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
     site: 'https://auth.example.com/oauth2/token')

    access_token = client.password.get_token(username, password)
    Rails.logger.info access_token.token
  end
```

What I get after visiting localhost/test is Completed 500 Internal Server Error with OAuth2::Error saying that page that I look for doesn't exist.

When trying just use curl from command line with respective data, I recieve:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Doorkeeper", error="invalid_grant", error_description="The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."
```

Please kindly advise what may cause problem in these set-up.

Comment: So CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET are your environment variables? Where did you set your environment variables?
The site is wrong. If you want to test this in development the site should be `site: 'https://127.0.0.1:3000'` 3000 If your server is using port 3000. Also you need to have  `client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2/callback'` If you use port 8080. So did you follow the instructions at page or I am just totally wrong? I never used this but I configured Devise and Omniauth-Facebook and they are very similar https://github.com/intridea/oauth2

Comment: CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET in my code are replaced with actual data, I just didn't want to reveal it on SO. Server to which I want to connect is not developed by me, I only have data which should allow to authenticate and then use their api. As far as I know, setting up callback doesn't apply here as it is authenticated by password grant.

Comment: You are right !

Comment: I have read many discussion, some people suggest that you should not pass client_id and client_secret, the required parameters for the refresh token are `grant_type` and `refresh_token`.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548977/oauth2-password-grant-type-with-doorkeeper-and-angular?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689168/401-unauthorized-invalid-grant-when-requesting-refresh-token-in-doorkeeper?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please, take under consideration that I want to get access_token not refresh_token. Your first link says that we should not use client_id / client_secret on web browser apps, mine is on server-side. You're right that client_id / client_secret may be unnecessary overhead nowadays. I also saw this kind of suggestions, in my implementation above I use Intridea oauth2 gem which enforces using this data in constructor. [#initialize](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/intridea/oauth2/OAuth2/Client#initialize-instance_method)

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Finally, I figured it out, it turned out that there is need to declare token_url explicitly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. I am glad you figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems I overlooked one important thing, we should declare explicitly `token_url` in relation to `site` address and not treat `site` parameter as entire path.

So in order to request `access_token` my method should look like this:

```
def test
  client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id,
                                client_secret,
                                token_url: "/oauth2/token",
                                site: "https://www.example.com/" )

  access_token = client.password.get_token(username, password)
  Rails.logger.info access_token.token
end
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236193/oauth2-with-intridea-ruby-gem) you can find similar issue to mine.

If someone wants to get access token with password credentials using simple http method, here is example how to approach this thing:

```
def test
  param = {
          :client_id => client_id,
          :client_secret => client_secret,
          :grant_type => 'password',
          :username => username,
          :password => password
        }

  uri = URI.parse(service_url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  http.use_ssl = true
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  request.body = param.to_query
  response = http.request(request)

  Rails.logger.info response.body()
end
```